# Unable to get send_mail to send an email message Django

Tags: django, django-settings, django-email

I posted a question earlier where I asked how to get my email to send and was told that it's the provider, so I tried 3 providers and the send_mail and/or EmailMessage function doesn't work with any of them.

So, I strongly think it's something related to my set-up. I get a message in the send_email folder, but no email ever sends and no error is logged.

Here is my settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemails@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
```

Might someone else have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried with `fail_silently=False`?

Comment: Yes, and there is no error.

Comment: Did you create a Google App token for Gmail? You know you can't just use your Google Account password here.

Comment: No, I just tried to use gmail, zoho and yahoo and none worked as is. What is a google app token?

Comment: I'm a beginner is there a good tutorial or link?

Comment: I think this is related to IMAP issues. Otherwise you can use a mail API like mailgun or sendgrid

Comment: I also advice using an API based solutions like mailgun. They are meant for this purpose and I'm sure there a far more resources to help implementing. That said, to create an App Password you go to your account myaccount.google.com > Security > App Passwords > Generate. Try putting the generated token into the `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` field.